# SERVER CORE : Running .net applications

Tags: .net, windows-server-core

I have a number of very memory/cpu intense .net applications that would like to look at moving to 2008 R2 server core,  core seems like the perfect solution from initial review, we have a lot of Server 2003 VM's that were P to V's and I think we are wasting a lot of host resources on these. All apps run on either .net 3.5 or 4, is there a problem with using server core like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2008 R2 Server Core only supports a *subset* of .NET.  Here's the documentation on Server 2008 R2 and .NET:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff770052(v=winembedded.60).aspx

> On a Server Core installation and on a full installation of Windows
>   Server, you can enable the .NET Framework by installing the optional
>   features for it. You cannot enable the .NET Framework by using the
>   downloadable .NET Framework redistribution packages.

So upon first inspection, no .NET 4 for you. But I think that documentation is a tad outdated, and you can still find an installer for .NET 4 specifically for Server Core...

Yep, here it is:  http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=22833

But you're likely still going to be limited in what .NET namespaces are supported in 2008 R2 Core:

> Server Core contains the normal complement of .NET namespaces with a
>   few exceptions. This list contains, by name, the namespaces that are
>   missing from a Server Core installation.
>
> • System.ComponentModel.Design
>
> • System.Data.Design
>
> • System.Deployment.Application
>
> • System.Diagnostics.Design
>
> • System.Media
>
> • System.Messaging
>
> • System.Speech 
>   • System.Web.UI.Design
>
> Design time support is unavailable. Runtime support for expression builders is supported.
>
> • System.Windows
>
> • Microsoft.Aspnet.Snapin
>
> • Microsoft.lnk
>
> • Microsoft.ManagementConsole
>
> • Microsoft.StylusInput
>
> • Microsoft.VisualBasic.Compatibility.VB6
>
> • Microsoft.Windows.Themes
>
> • Microsoft.WindowsCE.Forms
>
> • Microsoft.WindowsMobile.DirectX
>
> •UIAutomationClientsideProviders